# Docker pass arguments to docker without replacing default CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am writing a dockerfile that runs a pp that wil use the same argument most of the time.

```
ENTRYPOINY [ "mayapp" ]
CMD [ "defaultarg" ]
```

But every now and the it needs to take another argument, since the users will be mostly windows I want to do this without many scripts or extra arguments

```
docker run my/app somearg
```

Issue is they need to use a bind volume. However when I add a -v switch it will take that to override the CMD.

```
docker run my/app -v datadir:/app/datadir
```

This will replace 'defaultarg' with '-v'
Is there a way to stop this from happening without moving the CMD arg to a env/ARG?

I have used the build args switch because I couldn't find any info. However resolving this without build-args would be nicer since it less switches on running the container.

Comment: That `-v` is a docker argument, right? You need to put it before the image. `docker run -v datadir:/app/datadir my/app`.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote this but this and the answer by @hans-killian was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters on `docker run` come in 2 flavours. Parameters for docker are placed before the image name and parameters for the container are placed after the image name. As you've discovered, parameters for the container replace any CMD statement in the image.

The `-v` parameter is for docker, so it should go before the image name, like this

```
docker run -v datadir:/app/datadir my/app
```

That will leave your CMD intact, so it'll work as before.